# smsgateway.me - SMS Gateway API and Android

Tags: php, android, sms, gateway, sms-gateway

I've updated everything for their new API v4 and also the new Android application (the old one was removed from the Play Store).

Now I'm having a problem with the messages in application running android 5.0, I've to press "Check Server Now" everytime to check for new messages (which are sent to API correctly but gets the status Pending until I press in the app manually).

I still have the application in a old Android running 4.0 (and at this one I could press the buttom for the option and change the frequency of the request).

The messages get to pending and have to press in the application everytime. Is someone having the same issue? Or anyone knows a workaround?

I've search everywhere and didn't find anything. I don't know if their new app in Google Play Store has new features, but probably I'm going to install the old version into the new smartphone (if possible - I don't usually work with Android).

Comment: Solved it, I made a backup from the old .apk in other Android and ran it in the new one. Seems to work and send correctly.

Comment: Hi @sinopia, would you kindly share the older APK ? It stopped working for me too :(

Comment: Hi. It stopped working again. The last version now say that require internet.. They've updated to a new version 4.1.1 but it keep crashing on mine.

Answer (score 0):

I actually could use it in a Samsung Galaxy A3 2017. It came with 5.0 and app also crashes but I started update to 6.0 and 7.0 and it worked... so I'll try in other device to update at least with 6.0 and should solve this issue.